# Restlet : Use converter service in filter

Tags: java, rest, restlet, restlet-2.0

I am using spring and restlet in a project.

I have added a filter which checks whether the request URI is valid or not and returns the list of valid URIs (resource discovery mechanism).

I have to return the response in json/xml using converter service(or conneg service) depending on the ACCEPT header. In filter, I am getting response object. I create an object of a custom class and populate it with the valid urls. To pass this object to response, I create a string representation(media type - json) of the object using json serializer and set the entity of response.

```
@Override
protected int beforeHandle(Request request, Response response) {    
    String relativeUri = request.getResourceRef().getRemainingPart();
    if(mappings.containsKey(relativeUri)) {
        return Filter.CONTINUE;
    }

    ArrayList<String> nextLevelURIs = getNextLevelResourcesUri(request);

    if(nextLevelURIs == null) {
        return Filter.CONTINUE;
    }

    Items items = getItems(nextLevelURIs);

    response.setEntity(serializer.serialize(items), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    return Filter.STOP;
}
```

To achieve what converter service does, I have to check the ACCEPT header and create the respective representation(json/xml). But I am already using converter service in other resource classes.

Is there any way to use converter service in filter. If I set json string representation and return Filter.CONTINUE, can converter service convert entity from json representation to xml representation or vice versa, depending on the ACCEPT header?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Found a way to do this. See the code.

```
@Override
protected int beforeHandle(Request request, Response response) {    
    String relativeUri = request.getResourceRef().getRemainingPart();
    if(mappings.containsKey(relativeUri)) {
        return Filter.CONTINUE;
    }

    ArrayList<String> nextLevelURIs = getNextLevelResourcesUri(request);

    if(nextLevelURIs == null) {
        return Filter.CONTINUE;
    }

    if(!request.getMethod().equals(Method.GET)) {
        response.setStatus(Status.CLIENT_ERROR_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED);
        return Filter.STOP;
    }

    ArrayList<Variant> variantList = new ArrayList<Variant>();

    Application application = getApplication();

    variantList.add(new Variant(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML));
    variantList.add(new Variant(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

    Variant variant = application.getConnegService().getPreferredVariant(variantList, request, application.getMetadataService());

    Items items = (relativeUri.equals("/")) ? getVersionItems(nextLevelURIs) : getItems(nextLevelURIs);

    try {           response.setEntity(application.getConverterService().toRepresentation(items, variant, null));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new ServerException(e.getMessage());
    }

    return Filter.STOP;
}
```